# How can I get the Car Home app to work?

Tags: 4.4-kitkat

I'm running KitKat and can't locate the Car Home app on it. It's listed in the Play Store as "Installed" and also "incompatible with all your devices", also "not eligible".

There's a seeming incongruency in the app install versus availability, and an inability to access the the app on my devices: no icon, no ability to add a shortcut to the launcher?

I've not seen another app in the Play store reporting itself in this odd manner.  My immediate assumption is it has been discontinued and/or is installed in the Android OS but only makes itself available under certain conditions (e.g. a docking station is present).

There does seem to be discussion around the Internet about the Car Home app and docking station integration.

Back in Gingerbread days I used to open the Car Home app manually to use it.  I haven't checked for it in a while.

Currently I'm running a Nexus4 with KitKat but I think this doesn't seem to matter. The app also won't work with my Note 10.1 and is not available for the old Nexus S either (lost that phone though so I'm only going by what the Play store is reporting for it).

I've settled for using a third-party app for now, however if Car Home is part of Android and the Play store I would prefer to use it.

Answer (score 1):

I use [Car Mode Ultra](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=spinninghead.carhome). It's highly customizable and more useful than the old car mode from Google

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 ways I have seen things that existed on the phone that did not have a application button, or shortcut.

AnyCut (or better cut) Anycut can make shortcut widget things for almost anything , all the normal things are already in it (the apps you know). There is also this huge list of junk that is not easy to navigate , and sometines is very poorly marked Like every settings item in existance.
Better cut attempts to assemble the data better in catagories, but not all items will exist in better cut.
With Anycut I have made direct buttons for deep settings items, and stuff I never even heard of.  Any Cut might be useful for finding stuff, and setting it up with an icon to run.

Any good explorer, with the option to see hidden, even though without root you wont be doing much with it.  Duel file manager, astro, ghost commander, just about any of them except the built in file managers which are often more simple.
With the explorers viewing and even searching for all items on the device, I found the jelly bean easter egg executable, and ran it, before ever knowing it was an easter egg.  Searching with a wildcard etc.  Most of these explorers have some way to run things that will run, or view.

Never know what you can find :-)  That is a few ways to look. I am runing testing now on the app called Ultimate Car Dock , it is large button interface voice interaction, shorts contactcs and apps. read and replay to messages with voice It is "ok" so many others did not even get this far. 7day trial pay app.

Analisis of UCD , it works , it has to be task ended with its services set to task end to stop working , or be reset in settings. It was not so easy to get it to stop, which is both good and bad, good that a lot of programs fail over time, so this did not.
Needs more settings to reduce the interaction as the method is learned, eventually a person wants to tell it to shut-up and visually present less info.
Has the same fatal flaw with voice recognition that most everything else has, a "translate to text first" approach, then "programatically compare the STT text" that was poorly recognised. (this method would work if there was a large "sounds like" compare for the limited choise triggers).
Other than that it was fully operational, very usable by clear speakers and TTS knowlegable, very frustrating for mumbling non-tech people.